# Checksums and file padding - trouble understanding EOT spec

Tags: fonts, padding, checksum, file-format, eot

I expect few of you will know much about EOT files (I don't think anyone does), but you might perhaps know enough about file formats in general to shine some light on this problem.

I'm able to read an EOT font in Python just fine, but after modifying some of the header fields and recomputing the checksums the resulting file is rejected by Internet Explorer.

There are two checksums, one for the RootString field and another for the whole font file. The spec can be found here: https://www.w3.org/Submission/EOT/#Version22

When I parse an EOT file and recompute its ChecksumAdjustment I get a number that doesn't match the one in the file, but if I save the file with this different checksum, it still works. However, if I actually make any modification to the font, such as changing the font's name, it will no longer work.

If the checksums aren't the problem, I thought it might have to do with the padding fields, which I'm struggling to comprehend the purpose of. Apparently, the padding is to ensure ULONG (4 byte) alignment. Some of the header fields are of a custom length, so presumably the padding is used when a custom length field breaks the alignment. But then what's the purpose of the first padding field? There are no custom length fields preceding it and the padding occurs at a multiple of 4 bytes anyway so why is it needed? Furthermore, the file I have (which I know works) has *every* 2-byte padding field even where it breaks alignment.

Here is how I'm parsing the file:

```
def __init__(self, file_path):
    super().__init__(base.FontType.EOT)

    self._file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        self.eot_size = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.font_data_size = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.version = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.flags = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.font_panose = struct.unpack('<10s', f.read(struct.calcsize('<10s')))[0]
        self.charset = struct.unpack('<s', f.read(struct.calcsize('<s')))[0]
        self.italic = struct.unpack('<s', f.read(struct.calcsize('<s')))[0]
        self.weight = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.fs_type = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.magic_number = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.unicode_range_1 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.unicode_range_2 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.unicode_range_3 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.unicode_range_4 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.code_page_range_1 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.code_page_range_2 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.checksum_adjustment = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.reserved1 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.reserved2 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.reserved3 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.reserved4 = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.family_name_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.family_name = f.read(self.family_name_size).decode('utf-16')
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.style_name_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.style_name = f.read(self.style_name_size).decode('utf-16')
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.version_name_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.version_name = f.read(self.version_name_size).decode('utf-16')
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.full_name_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.full_name = f.read(self.full_name_size).decode('utf-16')
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.root_string_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.root_string = f.read(self.root_string_size).decode('utf-16')
        self.root_string_checksum = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.eudc_code_page = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self._eat_padding(f)
        self.signature_size = struct.unpack('<H', f.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
        self.signature = f.read(self.signature_size)
        self.eudc_flags = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.eudc_font_size = struct.unpack('<L', f.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        self.eudc_font_data = f.read(self.eudc_font_size)
        self.font_data = f.read(self.font_data_size)

    _assert_equal(self.family_name_size, len(self.family_name.encode('utf-16-le')))
    _assert_equal(self.style_name_size, len(self.style_name.encode('utf-16-le')))
    _assert_equal(self.version_name_size, len(self.version_name.encode('utf-16-le')))
    _assert_equal(self.full_name_size, len(self.full_name.encode('utf-16-le')))
    _assert_equal(self.root_string_size, len(self.root_string.encode('utf-16-le')))


def _eat_padding(self, f):
    L = struct.calcsize('<L')
    H = struct.calcsize('<H')

#    f.read(H)
#    return

    excess = f.tell() % L
    if excess != 0:
        assert excess % H == 0, 'Font not USHORT aligned'
        bytes = f.read(L - excess)
        assert bytes == b'\x00' * (L - excess), 'Found non-zero padding bytes'
```

Here is how I export the file and compute the checksums:

```
def dump(self, f):
    self._compute_root_string_checksum()

    buf = io.BytesIO()

    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.eot_size))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.font_data_size))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.version))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.flags))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<10s', self.font_panose))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<s', self.charset))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<s', self.italic))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.weight))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.fs_type))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.magic_number))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.unicode_range_1))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.unicode_range_2))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.unicode_range_3))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.unicode_range_4))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.code_page_range_1))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.code_page_range_2))
    checksum_adj_pos = buf.tell()
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.reserved1))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.reserved2))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.reserved3))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.reserved4))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.family_name_size))
    buf.write(self.family_name.encode('utf-16-le'))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.style_name_size))
    buf.write(self.style_name.encode('utf-16-le'))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.version_name_size))
    buf.write(self.version_name.encode('utf-16-le'))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.full_name_size))
    buf.write(self.full_name.encode('utf-16-le'))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.root_string_size))
    buf.write(self.root_string.encode('utf-16-le'))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.root_string_checksum))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.eudc_code_page))
    self._add_padding(buf)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<H', self.signature_size))
    buf.write(self.signature)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.eudc_flags))
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.eudc_font_size))
    buf.write(self.eudc_font_data)
    buf.write(self.font_data)

    total = 0
    buf.seek(0)
    while True:
        bytes = buf.read(4)

        if len(bytes) == 0:
            break

        assert len(bytes) % 4 == 0, 'Font not padded correctly'

        ulong = struct.unpack('<L', bytes)[0]
        total = (total + ulong) & 0xffffffff

    self.checksum_adjustment = (0xB1B0AFBA - total) & 0xffffffff

    buf.seek(checksum_adj_pos)
    buf.write(struct.pack('<L', self.checksum_adjustment))

    buf.seek(0)
    while True:
        bytes = buf.read(1)

        if len(bytes) == 0:
            break

        f.write(bytes)


def _compute_root_string_checksum(self):
    root_string = self.root_string.encode('utf-16-le')
    buf = io.BytesIO(root_string)

    total = 0
    while True:
        bytes = buf.read(4)

        if len(bytes) == 0:
            break

        assert len(bytes) % 4 == 0, 'Root String not padded correctly'

        ulong = struct.unpack('<L', bytes)[0]
        total = (total + ulong) & 0xffffffff

    self.root_string_checksum = total ^ 0x50475342
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Question 1: why are you working with EOT? EOT is no longer necessary, as IE supports WOFF just like everyone else does, which is far better (and yes, I know EOT. It's similar to WOFF in that it's just OpenType with an extra header, except unlike WOFF, no one else supports it because it's a dead spec at this point in time. Webfonts went through quite a bit of flux, and settled on the WOFF/WOFF2 format. The w3.org spec you cite is from almost six years ago, which in webfont land is pretty much "before we seriously started using webfonts" =).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the response. My client wants to support EOT presumably as a fallback for users of old IE versions.

Comment: then you probably need to talk to your client, because [*literally today*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) Microsoft abandoned IE8 and below. They're no longer supported, they're no longer maintained, they're no longer endorsed. Not even for companies that pay Microsoft lots of money for past-EOL support. which is handy, because IE9 and above support WOFF. Adding EOT support at this point is literally wasting time and money.

Answer (score 0):

look here https://github.com/westmon/formhub/blob/af43646848106d06fbd5a82c90b9f0f6ab43613a/public/assets/plugins/ionicons/builder/scripts/eotlitetool.py

```
eot.checkSumAdjustment  = otf - > head -> offset + 12
```